# Kendo - rename 'skip' and 'take' parameters

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to use Kendo UI in an existing application.
The application reads parameters "limit" and "offset" from the request for paging DB results.
Kendo UI's `dataSource` object, however, passes these parameters named as "take" and "skip"

Is there a way to tell Kendo to send these values using custom keys, so it can follow the same convention as the rest of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported natively, but you can achieve this easily enough yourself:

```
function parameterMapPaging(data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('take')) {
        data.limit = data.take;
        delete data.take;
    }
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('skip')) {
        data.offset = data.skip;
        delete data.skip;
    }
    return data;
}
```

And call this from your datasource [parameterMap](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.parametermap) function:

```
var myData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/myEndpoint",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        parameterMap: function (data) {
            return JSON.stringify(parameterMapPaging(data));
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true // enable serverPaging so take and skip are sent as request parameters
}
```

The link to the kendo documentation contains an even simpler implementation, but essentially the solution is to reshape your request in the `parameterMap` function before it is sent. This is the stated purpose of that function:

> The function which converts the request parameters to a format suitable for the remote service

As an aside, you may also find the [parse](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schema.parse) function useful to reshape the response before it's used.